# how to check weather the function exist before calling the function using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am trying to check weather the function is exist before calling the function.
its my code

```
  function text(){ 
    for($i=0;$i<count($type);$i++){     
      $this->type=$type[$i];
        if($rec){ 
          if(function_exists($this->type)){
            $this->$type[$i]($rec);     
      }         
   }
  } 
}
```

and my $type will be

```
Array
(
  [0] =type_1
  [1] =type_2
  [2] =type_3
  [3] =type_4
  [4] =type_5
  [5] =type_6
  [6] =type_8
)


function type_1()
{
    ////
}
function type_2()
{
    ////
}
```

but its not working..

any help will be approciate.

thankx

Comment: `but its not working`.Whats the error.?

Comment: can not call the function,        function_exists()no calling my function

Comment: "if($rec){ "  where is $rec define ? I guess you have to define $rec before calling if condition other wise it will consider as false....

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can change your code from:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($type);$i++){     
$this->type=$type[$i];
if($rec){ 
   if(function_exists($this->type)){
        $this->$type[$i]($rec);     
  }
```

}
}

To

```
for($i=0;$i<count($type);$i++){     
$this->type=$type[$i];
if($rec){ 
   if(function_exists($this->type_1()){ // checks if type_1 function exists
        $this->$type[$i]($rec);     
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.. works here

```
<?php
$arr = array(0=>'typefunc',1=>'newfunc');

function typefunc()
{
echo "Hello my name is typefunc()";
}

foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
if(function_exists($v))
{
$v();
}
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Hello my name is typefunc()
```